# node.js nodemailer subject issue

Tags: node.js, encoding, nodemailer

i'm using the nodemailer library to send emails to my users.
The problem is that some special charachter such us "è" or "à" are not visible.
Can i change the encoding of the subject? in the body is already working.

```
var mailOptionsUtente = {
    from: 'my@email.it', // sender address
    to: utente.email, // list of receivers
    subject: "non è possibile", // Subject line
    html: "HTML...."
```

};

Answer (score 0):

i know you can add encoding option in your object.
See here 
https://community.nodemailer.com/

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Nodemailer encoding seems to doesn't care of the object field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add subject encoding options like that :

```
var subject = 'non è possibile';
var mail = {
    ...,
    subject: {
        prepared: true,
        value: '=?UTF-8?B?'+new Buffer(subject).toString('base64')+'?='
    },
    ...
};
```

source : https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/562